# R retrieve the twitter text from a twitter list

Tags: json, r, twitter, httr

I am trying to retrieve the twitter text from a twitter list I am downloading:

```
options(httr_oauth_cache=T)
setup_twitter_oauth("xxx",
                "xxx",
                "xxx",
                "xxx")

twlist<-searchTwitter("barcos", n=5000 , geocode='-0.206103,-78.495530,40km')
twcon<- fromJSON(content(content(twlist, "text")))
```

but I am getting this error with content:
Error in content(twlist, "text") : unused argument ("text")

Comment: First guess is to replace `content` with `httr::content`. You probably have another package that exports its own `content` function with only one argument. Second, why are you wrapping `content` with a second `content` call? Only one should be required.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, I have just run this example and `twlist` is a list of `status`, hence `content` raises an error `is.response(x) is not TRUE`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use `rtweet`, instead of `twitteR` which is not longer maintained. Use `search_tweets` instead of `seachTwitter` and on your `twlist` just do `twlist$text` to get the tweets. If you still face problems, just post them. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you but I am getting this error: Error in readRDS(pat) : error reading from connection

Comment: Does search_tweets has any parameters so I can filter by geolocation, equivalent to search_tweets parameter "geocode = '40.757343,-73.848261,40km'"?